# magento 2.2 where to paste command line

Tags: magento2.2, command-line

i want to enable my new theme's ( cleversoft novetty theme) extensions. and it wants me to run following command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

but as i am new to Magento i don't know where to place this code.... can someone guide me where to paste this code and run the command please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Log in to your Magento server via SSH.
2. Change to the directory in which you installed the Magento software.
3. Run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

After setup:upgrade you need to run the following commands if you are in production mode

`php bin/magento cache:flush`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: thanks miroslav petroff but can you explain it with any images or screen shots plz.

Comment: where is your magento installed. Locally on or on remote server?

Comment: i installed it on remote server

Comment: then you should get the SSH login credentials, log into the remote server using putty or some other terminal; navigate to magento root folder and execute the commands